# can we create two observer with same event in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer

I need to create one observer after the customer is logged in.

I found this is the event name **customer_login**

My point is I installed one third-party module for some requirement.
Where that extension has already created that event for their requirement.

I need to create it for some purpose in my own module.

So can I create it in my module? Is that is allowed to create the same event multiple times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Yes you can create multiple observer for same event

Its broadcast and listener kind of relationship

where the `dispatch` code is broadcaster and the all observers are listeners

even you can observe same event multiple times in your single module

Comment: So, once we create multiple observer for same event, all the code written in each observer will be fired is it?

Comment: @jafarpinjar exactly

Comment: @jafarpinjar the only thing is the order of observer called depends on which module load first

Comment: That's great @murtuza, Its helped me. Thank you

Comment: @jafarpinjar you are always welcome :)

Comment: I am stuck with on more issue, could you give me solution?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/240352/how-to-update-customer-address-using-custom-api-in-magento2

Comment: @jafarpinjar, if my answer solves your concern then feel free to mark as accepted so it will help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use an event multiple time, but main problem is it's observer firing order and it's controls.

My suggestion is create a separate module with dependency of current third party module, which is currently using same event and dispatch a you own event.

Comment: Hi what do you mean about "module with dependency" ? how can you achive that, thanks